# cannot read JSON file

Tags: java, json, maven

I'im trying to read my **JSON file** (size : **255Mo** ) in the **format** like this :

```
{    
    "Data":[
        {
          "IDJointure": "001",
          "societe": "societe1",
          "heure": "04"   
        },
        ... 
      ]
}
```

**Here is my code Java :**

```
      JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
         
        Object object = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("Data2019.json"));
        JSONObject jsonObject=(JSONObject) object;
        
          JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Data");

             for (int index = 0; index < arr.size(); index++) {

                 JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) arr.get(index);
                 String IDJointure = (String) jobj.get("IDJointure");
                 System.out.println(IDJointure);
                
                 String societe = (String) jobj.get("societe");
                 System.out.println(societe);
                 
             }
```

**But i had this error:**

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project Instanciation1: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Is the problem caused by the size of the JSON file ?

**The stack trace of errors :**

```
Error stacktraces are turned on.
Scanning for projects...
                                                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Instanciation1 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ Instanciation1 ---
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedList.linkFirst(LinkedList.java:131)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedList.addFirst(LinkedList.java:297)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:157)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:92)
    at com.mycompany.instanciation1.readjson.main(readjson.java:21)
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 55.284 s
Finished at: 2020-08-07T12:58:09+02:00
Final Memory: 8M/30M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project Instanciation1: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project Instanciation1: Command execution failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:302)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:289)
    ... 22 more
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: "`To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.`" - Do that, and show us the stacktrace.

Comment: By the way, what does 255Mo mean?

Comment: @StephenC sorry,  i mean 255 Megabyte and for the stack trace of errors is below .

Comment: For parsing large JSON Files you better stick with Jackson and the streaming api. Just a suggestion, this way you do not need to increase the heap size of your JVM.